# Validate combinatory list from excel file?

Tags: excel, database, validation, combinations

I have an excel file that contains a list of letter combinations. Something like this:

```
HRET
HERE
IJHD
TREE
etc.
```

How can I validate this list so that the result would yield which combinations are in fact real, existing words?

Any ideas anyone? 
Much appreciated!

Tom

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way would be to do this with spell check [as is explained here](https://www.automateexcel.com/spell-check-excel-vba/). Otherwise you would have to import a full dictionary in your file and check the letter combinations against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating whether a list of random letters contains actual words can be done by using the built in spelling checker in excel like so:

```
Sub Highlight_Misspelled_Words()
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cell.Text) Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Next
End Sub
```

This will only work for *words in the current spellcheck language*, and will highlight everything that isn't a (correctly spelled) word.

[source](https://www.automateexcel.com/spell-check-excel-vba/)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to let me know if you have any issues, or accept my answer if your problem is resolved.